# Posting as 'Answer your own question' didn't give initial reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

I've noticed that some of the upvotes that I earned for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556859/script-loses-permission-in-the-magic-method-destruct) didn't really count. Please, take a look at this ss:

[image]

Here we can see that I've earned the privilege to 'create tag synonyms' [red]. After that I earned 'Reviewer' badge. *(You'll see why I mention this)*

After the privilege and the badge, I got 40 reputation points [green], but my reputation got to 2,521 [yellow] (not to [the minimum needed for that privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)(2500) + 40). I didn't reach the rep cap [blue] - In fact, I've never reached rep cap. From `stackoverflow.com/reputation`:

> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days 
>   earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days

---

I checked the timestamps for the badge (`2016-07-24 18:23:05Z`) and for the question (`2016-07-24 21:14:52Z`) - Almost 3 hours in between them, so I didn't get the badge after posting. I've already waited 24+ hours before posting this.

---

I've checked "what's reputation", 'How does reputation work?', 'how do I audit my reputation' and some others... I even looked at the reputation tab with `show removed posts` activated, but I couldn't find anything related.

**I mention that question** because it's the one I posted with the `Answer your own question` option selected. Is there some kind of lock? Like, you only start getting reputation for that type of posts after some initial number of upvotes?

---

**Anyways, where is the missing reputation?** Or where can I figure out why it is what it is?

**Edit:** If I subtract the rep I got from that question / answer, I don't have enough for that privilege. Where did that achievement come from then?

Comment: I tried to put some effort before asking this. Am I missing something obvious? Forgive me if this is clear for you gurus, but I'm just lost here hoping it's my misunderstanding (or a desired behavior) rather than a bug ^^

Comment: According to [your profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4577762/firstone?tab=reputation&sort=post), all of the 7 upvotes were counted. I'd guess the order of events on the achievements popup might be wrong, but your reputation is correct.

Comment: @PetrR. Thanks for the reply... I thought that too (that maybe the points went up that list on more recent upvotes), but that's a 3 hour difference.. I checked the timestamps and the question was posted after the achievement. It's not like those points made me get it...

Comment: After doing a little math, it looks like you were at 2491 before the first upvotes on your question/answer. What likely happened is someone upvoted one of your answers and unupvoted it quickly. This leaves no record in your reputation history _but_ can trigger these privilege notifications because for a very short time, you _did_ have the rep for that privilege.

Comment: @Kendra that crossed my mind too. It's so sad we can't _audit_ that.. Nonetheless, thanks for the reply.